# Integrating Angular with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

I tried to connect angular front end with nodejs earlier I ran `ng build` on public folder of app and then ran localhost:3000. No error was given on compilation but app is broken now. Now do I achieve it? My folder structure is like this

- client
- public
- app.js

`client` contains all angular code, `public` contains compiled code of angular
till I have also changed output path to `../public` in `angular.json`.
And here is my `app.js`:

```
                 var express = require('express');
                 var path= require('path');
                   var cors = require('cors');
                    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
                     var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
                    var passport = require('passport');
                     var app= express();
                   var port = 3000;
                     app.set('view engine','ejs');
                //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
                 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
                 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
                 app.use('/api', routesApi);
                   app.get('/', (req,res) => {
                   res.send("Invalid page");
                             });
                   app.listen(port, () => {
              console.log(`Starting the server at port ${port}`);
                            });
```

Comment: Both of your server code(node.js) and frontend code(angular) are running without any errors?

Comment: yes before running ng build there was no error in front end or backend app was working fine

Comment: What happend after running ng build? Did you get any errors?

Comment: ng build didnt give any errors but when i run app it was broken when i copy the same code and again run it without runnnig  ng build on public folder to combine them whole app is working fine i dont know what is wrong with ng build

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think up to now you have a build of a **running angular application** and **perfectly running node.js server**.

What you have to do is host your client application. Follow the following steps to get this working.

1. Install [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) globally on your machine using `npm install http-server -g` command
2. Then run `http-server /path/to/your/dist/folder`. (You should get a dist folder after running `ng build --prod`)
3. Then run your node.js server.
4. And open your browser and go to http://localhost:8080